# After animating a widget with SizeTransition, it flickers back into view

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I wrote a Widget that animates items when adding\removing from a list.

*Note: I tried using AnimtedList, but it didn't seem to work with flutter_hooks*

here is the code:

```
class AnimatedTasksListByRating extends HookWidget {
  const AnimatedTasksListByRating(
      {super.key,
      required this.taskList,
      this.splashColor,
      this.checkboxActiveColor});

  final List<Task> taskList;
  final Color? splashColor;
  final Color? checkboxActiveColor;

  final Duration animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 400);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //TODO: fix edge-case: quickly tapping the filter chips messes with the animation
    //TODO: optimize - even checking one task rebuilds all of the lists

    //separate to 2 lists - so we can calculate the diff and animate accordingly
    final displayListState = useState<List<Task>>(taskList);

    //used to mark which items need to animate
    final indexToRemove = <int>[];
    final indexToAdd = <int>[];

    //animation controllers for adding and removing items
    final animController =
        useAnimationController(duration: animationDuration, initialValue: 1);

    final addAnim = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animController, curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic));

    final removeAnim = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animController, curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic));

    final columnChildren = <Widget>[];

    //check if animating from empty state
    if (taskList.isNotEmpty && displayListState.value.isEmpty) {
      displayListState.value.add(Task.placeholder);
    }

    //find all tasks that have been added, and call insertItem on them.
    for (int i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
      if (!displayListState.value.contains(taskList[i])) {
        displayListState.value.insert(i, taskList[i]);
        indexToAdd.add(i);
      }
    }

    //find all tasks that have been removed, and call removeItem on them.
    for (int i = 0; i < displayListState.value.length; i++) {
      if (!taskList.contains(displayListState.value[i])) {
        indexToRemove.add(i);
      }
    }

    //animating to empty state
    if (taskList.isEmpty && displayListState.value.isNotEmpty) {
      displayListState.value.add(Task.placeholder);
    }

    if (displayListState.value.isEmpty) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(
          'No Tasks Here',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
        ),
      );
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < displayListState.value.length; i++) {
      Widget toAdd;
      if (displayListState.value[i] == Task.placeholder) {
        //if we are moving to empty state - use the adding animation.
        //if we are moving from the empty state - use the removing animation
        final animToUse = indexToRemove.contains(i) ? removeAnim : addAnim;
        toAdd = SizeTransition(
          sizeFactor: animToUse,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'No Tasks Here',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else if (indexToRemove.contains(i)) {
        toAdd = SizeTransition(
          sizeFactor: removeAnim,
          child: TaskListItem(
            splashColor: splashColor,
            checkboxActiveColor: checkboxActiveColor,
            task: displayListState.value[i],
          ),
        );
      } else if (indexToAdd.contains(i)) {
        toAdd = SizeTransition(
          sizeFactor: addAnim,
          child: TaskListItem(
            splashColor: splashColor,
            checkboxActiveColor: checkboxActiveColor,
            task: displayListState.value[i],
          ),
        );
      } else {
        toAdd = TaskListItem(
          splashColor: splashColor,
          checkboxActiveColor: checkboxActiveColor,
          task: displayListState.value[i],
        );
      }

      columnChildren.add(toAdd);
    }

    if (indexToAdd.isNotEmpty || indexToRemove.isNotEmpty) {
      final currentState = 1 - animController.value;

      animController.forward(from: currentState).whenCompleteOrCancel(() {
        displayListState.value = taskList;
      });
    }

    return Column(children: columnChildren);
  }
}
```

in short, what it does is take the data list (taskList), compare it to the currently displayed list (displayListState.value), and flag items that need to be added/removed.

it works well, but is has 1 bug that I can't seem to figure out -
sometimes, items that have been removed will flicker back for a few frames and then disapear again.

[this is what it looks like](https://imgur.com/a/piP4zwD)

after the animation is finished I set the displayList to be the data list (taskList) in the `whenCompleteOrCancel` callback.
my guess is that it is sometimes a bit delayed? I am not sure.

thanks!